# Monitoring WebSphere JVM Metrics through Ganglia

Tags: java, linux, ganglia

I am new to this forum and also to Ganglia - We are trying to capture JVM metrics through Ganglia - I have followed the steps through this link - https://github.com/ganglia/jmxetric

### High Level - Installation

Unzip the archive
Add the following to your JVM

```
java -javaagent:<path>/jmxetric.jar=host="",port="",config="",process="" 
usual.java.main.class
```

Demo / Quickstart

This example works for version 1.0.6 of `jmxetric` and `gmetric4j`.

1. Ensure you have a gmond running on localhost:8649

   ```
   $ pgrep gmond # should return a valid PID
   $ nc localhost 8649 # dumps some XML to stdout
   ```
2. `$ git` clone same link as above
3. Download `jmxetric.jar`, `gmetric4j.jar` and `oncrpc-1.0.7.jar`
   all into the same directory.
4. `$ cd jmxetric`
5. In bash do:

   ```
   $ export config="host=localhost,port=8649,wireformat31x=true,config=etc/jmxetric.xml"
   $ java  -Djava.util.logging.config.file=etc/logging.properties \
       -cp gmetric4j-1.0.6.jar:oncrpc-1.0.7.jar:jmxetric-1.0.6.jar \
       -javaagent:jmxetric-1.0.4.jar=$config info.ganglia.jmxetric.JMXetricAgent
   ```

But when I Add the JVM Argument in WAS its not coming up and native sterr logs shows -
JMXetricAgent instrumented JVM, see same link what I have used
Test wakeup

and then in around every 10 mints it keeps on writing Test wakeup but instance does not starts.

Also I have tried to run java command through command line like this --

```
[root@hostname var]# java -javaagent:/etc/ganglia/jmxmetric/jmxetric-master/jmxetric-1.0.6.jar=host=hostname,port=8649,mode=unicast,wireformat31x=true,config=/etc/ganglia/jmxmetric/jmxetric-master/jmxetric.xml,process=hostanem_m01 info.ganglia.jmxetric.JMXetricAgent
```

Getting same response
JMXetricAgent instrumented JVM,
Test wakeup

Can you all please suggest as what I am doing wrong here.

Thanks much in Advance (its been a week I am struggling with this)

Comment: Member's can you please help with this issue - I am kind of stuck here

Answer (score 0):

"usual.java.main.class" is given just an example.. i believe you should remove it from JVM arguments.

Comment: Your answer seems a little bit incomplete. Can you please elaborate it more.